# How to duplicate method from DAL in BBL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using 3 tier architecture in my solution. I have 3 projects as: DAL, BLL, and Web application with controllers and views. In the DAL project, I have my model class, data context class, `IRepository`, and `Repository` class with realization.

What is the best sophisticated way to duplicate code and method from DAL to BLL? especially I`m interested in how to duplicate methods for CRUD operations?

Comment: You can start by spelling correctly and not yelling, please.

Comment: You can then improve upon that by reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The best way is to not duplicate code at all, regardless of application architecture. Why do you want to duplicate methods?

Comment: and how i can take information from DAL and transform to WEB?

Comment: @MR. m, You can give reference of DAL to your WEB

Comment: No, in ideal form the WEB know nothig about DAL

Comment: So, you are asking that without adding a reference how it can be done? right?

Comment: yeah, i know that in BLL we should create duplicated DTO model but how to make duplicate for methods in proper way...i don`t know

Comment: If you are just going to duplicate it, just elimitate BBL at all.

Comment: Or instead of duplication, you can add DLL of DAL in Web and use that through code.

Comment: If you said that you need a 'service layer' I would give it a second thought. But I abbandoned the 3 tier architecture, Ui<->BLL<->DAL, more than a decade ago. All their premises ended up being false. For examlple, modern Data Access like Entity Framework allows you to change the db engine without affecting UI or business logic, so there is no gain into wrapping the DAL inside the BLL. And I've haven't switched db engine very often anyway. I recommend you to just use MVC 5 or MVC Core where those deprecated rules have been rethought.

Comment: i mean service layer

Comment: You could introduce interfaces for the data needed in both DAL and BLL, put them into a "Contracts" project. Implement them on both the DAL models and corresponding BLL DTOs. Then build your logic based on these interfaces and put it into a project referenced by both DAL and BLL.

Comment: are there any example projects? because, it is my first experience in it.